Count the no. of strings separated by comma in a single row
Q. Category Product Count



category
products




Electronics
TV, Radio, Laptop


Furniture
Chair


Clothing
Shirt, Pants, Jacket, Shoes


Groceries
Rice, Sugar



Count the number of products in each category (It is assumed to be an Easy level question So maybe start with an easier rather than using user defined functions straight away)
All answers are appreciated though.
select category, count(CHAR_LENGTH(products) ) AS product_count
from categories
group by category
order by count(*) asc


You need to tag the RDBMS you use. What to do if another row appears with a category that already occured in a previous row? Should all products be counted or all distinct products?

Is this from a class, book or tutorial? This is exactly the way not to store data in a database.

Tag the request with your DBMS, so we know what SQL features are available.

Anyway, the key is to count commas. So either there is a function available to count commas or a function to remove commas so you can compare the original string length with the one without commas.

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result.

Ideally, if possible, normalize your table. Anything you have to parse is a symptom that the database is designed wrong. In this case, 1 category table and 1 product table.

Your SQL query is close but not correct. The count(CHAR_LENGTH(products)) part does not give you the correct number of products in each category.
Here is the simple approach.
Since the product is comma separated in the product columns, we can use COUNT function in combination with FIND_IN_SET to count the number of products.
Solution 1: without FIND_IN_SET
SELECT 
  category, 
  LENGTH(products) - LENGTH(REPLACE(products, ',', '')) + 1 AS product_count
FROM 
  categories
GROUP BY 
  category
ORDER BY 
  product_count ASC;

Solution2: With FIND_IN_SET
SELECT 
  category, 
  SUM(FIND_IN_SET(product, products) > 0) AS product_count
FROM 
  (SELECT 
     category, 
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(products, ',', numbers.id), ',', -1) AS product
   FROM 
     categories
   CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT id FROM numbers WHERE id <= (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(products) - LENGTH(REPLACE(products, ',', '')) + 1) FROM categories)) AS numbers
   ) AS subquery
GROUP BY 
  category
ORDER BY 
  product_count ASC;

How it will work

LENGTH(products) gives us the total length of the products.
LENGTH(REPLACE(products, ',', '')) gives us the length of the products string with all commas removed.
By Subtracting the two lengths, we get the number of commas in the product string.
Adding 1 to the result gives us the total count of the products in each category.


This is RDBMS-specific and therefore maybe totally useless. Better await OP tag theirs. And you write about FIND_IN_SET, but don't use it. So why do you mention it?

Yes, I Just saw that, let see what is it related. If its RDBMS then it's useless. Let's wait. I added both solutions.

Why the GROUP BY?

@JonasMetzler solution 1 is RDBMS agnostic

@Bohemian MSSQL doesn't provide a LENGTH function.

@JonasMetzler it has LEN() - close enough.
